# Java - glassfish - web service - local file access

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish-3, file-permissions, ubuntu-11.04

I am running a webservice using glassfish server on Ubuntu. The problem is - it is required to access a directory outside of its shared resource. Presently it is giving an error saying "Permission Denied". I set a permission into server.policy too.

```
grant codeBase "/home/glassfish/glassfish/test/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

But it seems not working.
I tried `<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=*.* dir=/home/glassfish/glassfish/test"/>` ,  but it seems it is giving only reading permission. I need write permission also. So my question is how can I set the write permission ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that the glassfish user has write permissions on the directory?

Comment: Yes glassfish users have read/write/execute all the permissions.

Comment: How are you accessing these files? Java File API or loading as a resource?

Comment: When logged in as the glassfish user, can you run "touch foo" in the given directory?  Have you tested that the permissions are set up correctly?  Also try testing with JVM security turned off to see if that is part of the problem.

Comment: Is it is `java.lang.SecurityException`, `java.io.FileNotFoundException`, or `java.io.IOException` ?  "Permission Denied" is too vague.

Comment: @Jim It is showing FileNotFoundException + Permission Denied

Comment: Ok, you've said that the user does have write permission, but have you _tested_ that it does by creating another file there manually? (touch foo)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a JavaSecurity problem so you shouldn't need to tweak anything in that regard.

FWIW our web-apps deployed to GF on various flavors of Windows write to directories which are outside of the 'Application' directory using File APIs. alternatedocroot pertains to GF serving static content using the DefaultServlet not to writing outside of the Application deployment directory.

On windows when you run as Service you have to be careful that the 'Run As' user has proper permissions to write to the target directory, on Unix you need to make sure the user set by your rc (init.d) scripts that runs asadmin.sh has permissions to read/write to the target directory.

I would double check the the user that the java process GF is running under has rwx permissions on the directory your are trying to write to. Make sure that user can write to the target folder. To test this you can su to the user and use the 'touch' command like so: touch /tmp/test and verify write permissions that way. Verify read permissions similarly by running 'ls -l /tmp/test' to make sure you can read it.

See what 'ps -ef | grep java' shows to verify the user running the GF java process.  Additionally in your code try specifying a full path to the test file, eg. File test = new File("/tmp/test");

Are you running GF from an rc script or are you starting it using asadmin.sh from a shell prompt? If you are running an rc script check that your rc script is really running it as the user you expect it to be.